# How do I convert this equation to polar coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry

Convert the equation $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 2xy$ into polar coordinates.

I tried converting the equation in the image to polar coordinates and got $r= \sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}$.

This answer is wrong, but I do not understand why. Can someone please explain what the correct answer is?

Comment: What is the answer given?

Comment: The answer was not provided.

Comment: You probably need both the positive and negative square roots.

Comment: Yeah that could be the only possibility.

Comment: There is not an option for that.

Comment: Does it say $r^2=\sin(2\theta)$?

Comment: What are the options? Is it a multiple choice question?

Comment: No. This is a free response question. There is no plus-minus sign in the system, and I tried square root of 2 sine theta times cosine theta as well.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link since links may be deleted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

*Did you get something similar to this?*

For the original equation $$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 2 x y$$

Let $$\begin {matrix} x = r \cos \theta \\ y = r \sin \theta \\ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \end {matrix}$$

Plugging all of this in to the original equation we get

$$(r^2)^2 = 2r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$$

or

$$r^4 = 2 r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$$

Dividing by $r^2$ we have

$$r^2 = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$$

However, $2 \sin \theta \cos \theta = \sin 2 \theta$ so we end up with

$$r^2 = \sin 2 \theta$$

We can leave as-is (I think this may be the answer they're expecting) or take square roots...

$$r = \pm \sqrt {\sin 2 \theta}$$

Comment: I think it's supposed to be square root of sine double angle.

Comment: Thanks, VRM - my mistake!  Fixed.